# Django Post model views example

Tags: django, list, python-3.x, view

I want to create a simple post model. How is the easiest and useful post creation, deletion, detail and listing for django?

Best regards

Comment: Maybe you should start reading the documentation or check some video tutorial for django. What you want is the basics of django and by knowing them you can do it in minutes.

Comment: Hi, I know there are many ways to do this. I wonder which model is used the most. Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to start is reading the tutorial:

> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Here you can learn everything about views, template and DBConnections

If your are looking for a blog, check all packages available for django here:

> https://djangopackages.org/grids/g/blogs/

or if you want a complete example check this:

> https://github.com/drager/django-simple-blog

Comment: Hi, I know there are many ways to do this. I wonder which model is used the most. Best regards

Comment: answer edited with more example for a blog, check again :)